# XCode - Tableview1 linked to Tableview2 then detailed view - XML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I know how to read an XML file containing categories for example and display them in a table view on my XCode (IOS 6).

What I'd like to do is how I could make a second table view to be displayed based on the clicked category to show its corresponding products?

XML --> TableView 1 (Show all categories) --> Click on a category --> Show TableView 2 listing all corresponding products.

**XML (categories)**

```
<categories>
 <name>A</name>
 <name>B</name>
 <name>C</name>
</categories>
```

**XML (products of Category A)**

```
<products>
 <product>Prod A1</product>
 <product>Prod A2</product>
 <product>Prod A3</product>
</products>
```

What I can see online is always a table view displaying a list based on whatever and then a detailed view. What I cannot find is 2 table views linked and then a detailed view and I'd appreciate if someone could help me providing me with an example link I could download an example code from.

Thanks

Comment: it would be nice to see what you already did

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a tableView1 - (navigationController) -> tableView2 -> (navigationController) -> detailView pattern.

On iPhone, you usually implement a first table view (with UITableViewController), and navigate to another screen containing another tableview etc.
 
On iPad, you could use the [UISplitViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/) to have a tableView and a detailView on the same screen (that's the main interest of the UISplitVC).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I was trying to do. I would have tableview1 to display the categories and tableview2 for the sub-categories. Then when clicking on a subcategory it would finally give the details. Do you have an example to provide?

Comment: I don't have an example to provide with code. But try to consider problems separately, then glue everything piece by piece. (tableview1, then tableview2, then navigation between the two... etc).

Answer (score 0):

- You can try for having only one table view which will be grouped/Plain 
  After clicking on the Cell expand the no. of rows and add the cells as per subcategories.

Or

- Create Two view controller holding UITableView for Main and Sub categories.
- Just pass the selected index to the sub categories UITableView and load the data respective to selection

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I was trying to do. I would have tableview1 to display the categories and tableview2 for the sub-categories. Then when clicking on a subcategory it would finally give the details. Do you have an example to provide?